# Map List<Future<Object>> into List<Object>

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a

```dart
List<Future<int>>
```

how do I transform it into a

```dart
List<int>
```

Comment: use a async method or futureBuilder depend on your case.Can you include more details.

Comment: I need to map it inside my Bloc method so can't use futureBuilder : /

Comment: you can make the method to async and loop though 1st list and await

Comment: yes how do I write the loop

Comment: use `Future.wait` and `await` it's result

Comment: thanks got it. There was an issue on my part

Comment: **`Future.wait` and `await` it's result** seems to do the job - thanks a lot guys!

Comment: `Future.wait(methods).then((value) { print(value);  });`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Credit goes to @pskink

This is how you can do it :

```dart
  List<int> resultSet = [];

  List<Future<int>> methods = [];

  resultSet = await Future.wait(methods);
```

You can also do it like this :

```dart
  List<int> resultSet = [];

  List<Future<int>> methods = [];

  await Future.wait(methods).then((value) {
    resultSet = value;
  });

  print(resultSet);
```

More about [Future/wait](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Future/wait.html)

Comment: `void main(List<String> args) async {
  List<int> resultSet = [];

  List<Future<int>> methods = [];

  resultSet = await Future.wait(methods);

  print(resultSet);
}` works too right ? : )

Comment: yes it will work

Comment: yes, it works too, I don't know why so many people mixes `Future.then` inside `async` method - it is almost always asking for possible troubles

Comment: You can write both in your answer this way I accept it  for future users : )

Comment: oh I just did to use print message 

Comment: feel free to update the answer

Answer (score 0):

If I have a hint at what you are trying to do, here is my suggestion.

- You have a future inside a list, meaning you should await the result of the class itself before adding it to your list.
- after doing that, you can then do something like this, to convert it to a map:

```
    var myMap = Map.fromIterable(myList, key: (myClassInstanceVariable) => myClassInstanceVariable.variable1, value: (myClassInstanceVariable) => myClassInstanceVariable.variable1Value);
```

I would have really loved it, if there was something like a more detailed explanation, so  I can see how to help you with the Future. for that, I would suggest future builder

```
FutureBuilder<YourClass>(
    future: theAsyncMethodThatGetsYourClass,
    builder: (context, snapshot){
    //some code
    });
```